# TabPage пропорциональное изменение

Tags: c#, winforms

Вопрос на первый взгляд простой но не знаю ответ на него. WinForms,  есть на форме объект TabPage,  как сделать так чтобы при изменении размеров формы - измеенялись пропорционально и размеры tabPage, и контроллов которые на нем расположены, то есть полная привязка к форме. Спасибо

Comment: Смотрите свойство `Anchor`

Comment: Также смотрите свойства `Dock` и `AutoSize`. Чтобы обеспечить правильное масштабирование, желательно использовать компоненты `TableLayoutPanel` и т. п. Смотрите руководства: [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/1zkt8b33(v=vs.110)), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w4yc3e8c%28v=vs.110%29), [3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3z3f9e8b(v=vs.110)).